# Why did Commodore 64 cartridge games disappear?

Tags: history, commodore-64, game-cartridge

The Commodore 64 has a cartridge slot, but by the mid-eighties, cartridge games disappeared; everything was on tape or disk. Why?

One answer that suggests itself is that by that time, a larger percentage of owners had disk drives. However, that was less true in Europe, and in America, if you ask why Nintendo replaced Commodore, one of the reasons usually given is the speed and convenience of cartridges over the slow and clunky 1541 disk drive, so why was there not a preference for the speed and convenience of cartridges on the 64?

It's true that cartridges cost more per unit to produce, but they also eliminate piracy; would this not offset the increased cost, from the vendor's viewpoint?

Comment: I think not having a 1541 was more a UK phenomenon. I did not know a single C64 kid which did not own a 1541 – Germany, ~1984.

Comment: By far did they not eliminate piracy, especially in the 80s where enough people were tech savy enough to copy some roms.

Comment: Cartridges vs tape/disc are like locks on windows or other home security measures.  They don't make it **impossible** to burgle a house, but they remove the easy win, which will lead to a **decrease** in piracy.  Piracy wise, getting a tape/disk and copying software onto it is trivial for everyone.  Messing about with blank roms isn't.

Comment: I had (made) a cart with a switch on it.  Close the switch and it would connect the R/notW line to the "cart not present" line. Read from the cart area, you got the RAM behind it.  Writes went to the ROM cart, i.e. writes to the RAM behind the cart failed.  You could load a game image into that RAM, flip the switch and it emulated ROM.  Simple as it was, it was a very closely guarded secret.

Comment: This question title is very, very misleading.  I thought you were talking about specific unavailability of any old C64 cartridges from collectors or musty ol' basements.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Would "messing about with blank roms" have actually been necessary? Given the small size of ROMs at the time, wouldn't a pirate have been able to dump the ROM and distribute the resultant program via floppy?

Comment: @jmbpiano I don't know, as I don't know about the specific rom cart architecture.  There might be the equivalent of a boot sector or something similar - something to make it not as simple as just copying it.  Also, copying a tape requires no technical expertise at all, whereas dumping a rom requires some knowledge at least.  I probably couldn't have done it when I was 12, which was when I was swapping tapes of copied ZX Spectrum games in the playground.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Time to market was another factor.   I worked in the games industry in the 1980s and when we were getting the final game from the developer, mastering to cassette and disk took just hours before they went into production and (typically leading up to Christmas) they were in the shops just 48 hours later.

Often there would be a bug found and disks would be re-written with the new version and again in to the shops 48 hours later.

Cartridge production had lead times of 12-16 **weeks**.  Once you had a cartridge, it was a lot of money tied up in inventory that couldn't be reused or changed in the event of a bug being found.

Comment: ... or in event of the game turning out to be a flop (cf Atari 2600 ET)

Comment: @Jules: Atari's production volumes for E.T. were excessive.  The game sold decently well and was enjoyed by people who took the time to *read the instructions*.

Comment: @supercat - sure, maybe "flop" is putting it too bluntly for that specific case -- but you can bet that whoever decided what volume to order had at least a reasonably good understanding of typical sales figures, which shows that predicting that kind of thing is *hard*.  If a big name like Atari can make the mistake of ordering significantly more copies than they turn out to be able to sell, that's a problem that a lot of others will have too.  So having to order extra cartridges that are not necessarily going to sell is an expense that a smaller publisher could do without.

Comment: @Jules: If memory serves, the number of E.T. cartridges manufactured exceeded the number of Atari 2600 units that had been sold to date.  Although Atari expected to sell a significant number of Atari 2600 units that Christmas (and they did) there's no way they could have reasonably expected to sell all of the E.T. cartridges they produced.  On the other hand, many companies deliberately over-produce high-mark-up products so it they'll appear to be bursting off store shelves, and perhaps the execs at Atari were thinking along such lines.

Comment: @supercat Not only is 2600 ET not the worst game of all time, it's far from the worst 2600 game of all time too.

Answer (score 37):

A cartridge was limited to 16 kbytes ROM, and some were only 8k.  There would be plenty of RAM to use, but the code and data must fit into the 16 kbytes.  As programs became more sophisticated, the desire to make full use of the C64's sound, graphics, and sprites, ROM size would often be a limiting factor.  OTOH, a program loaded from disk (or for the patient, tape) could use two to three times what a cartridge offered for code and data.  Also, disks allowed for overlays and other memory to be overwritten dynamically.  Imagine an RPG -- when you leave once city or cave and enter another, you can replace the artwork and music with that of the new place.

I never felt that cartridges "died".  They were still fine for a lot of arcade style games, even using advanced SID techniques that were not known to early C64 developers.  But as you alluded, disks and tapes were less costly to produce.  Cartridges only had two advantages.  Programs would load quickly, and cartridge programs were more awkward to pirate.

Comment: But couldn't cartridges use bank switching to get around the 16K limit? Some cartridges on the NES (which has essentially the same CPU as the 64) contained hundreds of kilobytes of code and data.

Comment: Bank switching means that only some of the memory is accessable at once, making development harder. A disk or cartridge game can use 64k of flat address space. Also cartridges are more expensive to produce.

Comment: @PaulHumphreys, I think you meant "a disk or cassette game".

Comment: @rwallace, Yes, cartridges **could** have been built with some sort of bank-switched ROM.  It would not surprise me if such cartridges exist for the C64. But, unlike the NES and other consoles, the C64 had always been able to use disk and tape.  So it offered cheaper ways of producing programs and games than consoles of the era did.

Comment: Later cartridges had a packer and unpacked the game into RAM rather than running it from the ROM directly.

Comment: What about the C64GS soft relaunch cartridges? Battle Command, Shadow of the Beast et al? Those are definitely not 16kb games.

Comment: @RichF: Given that the C64 has 64K of RAM, there's really not much need for cartridges to use address space beyond the 8K needed to allow them to auto-start.  Adding a single 74LS174 or equivalent (a 16-pin DIP) would allow the address space for a cartridge to be easily expanded 64-fold.  Copying code from the cartridge to RAM before use really shouldn't be much of a handicap.

Comment: @PaulHumphreys sure, *if money is no object*.  Pro tip (literally), it was.

Comment: @RichF The Famicom (jap version of the NES) could use disks as well, using the Famicom Disk System. And guess what ? Disks were only widely used 1986 and 1987, by the end of that year they were already boldly replaced by cartridges, because that was supposedly more powerful and cheaper. So it's curious it's the oposite for the C64. Perhaps the fact it's different disks plays a major role.

Comment: @rwallace: It would have been trivial to interface a ROM of any size up to 512KB to a Commodore 64 in a cartridge that contained the ROM plus just one other chip.  Simply hook the data wires of a 74LS378 to A0-A5, the clock input to phi2, and the /G input to the DF00 strobe, and wire Q0-Q5 of the '378 to the upper address pins of the ROM.  Expanding to 2MiB would simply require using a '377 instead of a '378.

Comment: @rwallace: i think this wasn't done because a cartridge would have to grow to at least 32KiB, if not 64KiB, to do anything that couldn't be done with a cassette game, and while such ROM chips were available, their cost would have substantially eaten into per-unit profits and increased downside risks if a game didn't sell well.

Comment: @rwallace: A point I forgot to mention: if a game company executive were aware of how easy bank switching could be, a bank-switched cartridge could have offered a couple of enormous benefits: "loading" times could have been slashed, and piracy would have been far less practical than with disk-based or cassette-based games.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to RichF's answer, tapes were a lot cheaper than cartridges to manufacture. Tape duplication in the 80s was very low cost due to the high volumes involved, not least thanks to music distribution on the format.

Comment: Indeed, they used to give them away on the front of magazines. Those were the days.

Comment: +1 - I remember tapes were around £5 (or maybe £12-13 for brand new ones) while cartridges were well over £20. When you think of the demographic that games tended to be aimed at, tapes were a lot easier on the pocket money...

Comment: On further thought, I think the price issue also affects outlets. Budget games, often sold for £2 or £3, were packaged up so that a retailer bought e.g. a hundred of them, and essentially got a lucky dip. The target for producers of budget titles was newsagents, corner shops, and other places that might be willing to take a punt but which were unambiguously not computer or software shops. In the UK, at least, that's probably the sole way that many of us in smaller towns had access to commercial titles. The same business model obviously doesn't work for cartridges.

Comment: @colmde Actually, the demographic shift was *after* the video game crash - before (when cartridges were common), it was fun for everyone. Afterwards, Nintendo marketed video games as *toys for boys* to avoid the stigma. It's funny that Nintendo itself stuck to cartridges, while the competition largely switched over to cheaper alternatives (which fit the new demographic a lot better) - but it should also be noted that they probably assumed they will be bought by parents, not that kids would buy them from their pocket money (in Japan, Nintendo marketed for "the family").

Comment: @Luann - indeed, but if you had a Nintendo, you had no choice but to buy a cartridge and so they'd most likely be bought by parents. On the C64, you had the choice, and so kids could buy them with pocket money which was a lot easier for both them *and* the parents. I can imagine myself it would have taken a lot of pestering to get my parents to buy even one game on the Nintendo - it would be an occasional thing, (e.g. presents), But I had a C64 and I'd have been laughed for asking for £25 for a game when they were available for £5 - which I could have done myself almost on a whim.

Answer (score 18):

I know you specifically asked about cartridge "games". But another important factor in the market forces surrounding this was that the cartridge slot was ALSO the one "expansion" slot - A very limited resource on the C64.

As users and the market became more mature, there were many other uses for the cartridge/expansion slot, and these became competition for the limited resource. The most notable use-case being the Kernal firmware upgrades like the Epyx Fast Load cartridge, and all the copycats that followed. But there were also many I/O interfaces, memory expanders, "Freezers", and even high-speed disk interfaces competing for the same slot.

It is true that you could easily plug/unplug the various cartridges if you wanted to maintain access to some library of cartridge games too. And some people did this until it became widely known that the wear-and-tear on the slot was a common source of hardware failure. SO this practice fell out-of-favor fairly quickly.

Comment: As a C64 user, this was a primary reason for me to not even look at cartridge games anymore after a short time.

Comment: Definitely a large factor. Though, the wear-and-tear issue could be mitigated somewhat by cartridge switching devices similar to [the one shown here](http://atariage.com/forums/topic/223724-aprotek-aprospand-commodore-64128-4-port-cartridge-expander/). I didn't own one myself, but several of my friends with larger cartridge libraries did. The switch was left connected to the computer at all times and various cartridges would be swapped in and out on the switch with the most frequently used being removed least often. The Epyx FastLoad was *always* plugged in.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience the cartridge port (AKA expansion slot) of a C64 was problematic by design. If you look at a schematic of the 64, there is no buffering of any kind between the port and everything else on the bus - particularly the notoriously static-sensitive MOS chips at the heart of the system (e.g. the 6510 CPU). Perhaps this (and the product costs associated with cartridges) had some influence on the drive to use floppies and tape versus masked ROMs.

Comment: Wasn't this also a problem on the NES? Of course, it's not like the NES had any alternatives, so it doesn't really matter :D

Answer (score 4):

Had it in about 1983 I think and I saw just one cartridge: [Jaw Breaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_sGBlox4fs).

This was really beginning games for c64; after few time, me and my friends immediately went for tape; slower, bigger, but with better titles. First one I've got (after frying power charger and a month delay) was an adventure game whose name I don't remember who took some 30+ minutes to load from tape... Initially it was worth the while, what a magic when you could type some "go west" commands while listening to auld lang syne and some eerie blotchy graphics painted...

Anyway that doesn't in turn last for long as 1541 came in. In the beginning it was deadly slow it too but didn't care, I had been scrapping here and there just for buying it on the precise purpose of playing [Impossible Mission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivHFP3dJAkM), with all that luxury graphics and synthesized vocals and wonderful gameplay.

After a while, turbo loader for 1541 came in and everything went faster. No need to wait long times anymore. All this really happened in no more than 2 years I think, maybe less.

After that, the only other cartridge which I know of was a trap called [Isepic](http://rr.c64.org/wiki/ISEPIC), but that's a different one, you know... Anyway it plugged in the cartridge port where you could lock a couple pin and force system restart... In then end the same system cartridge games used to autostart...

Comment: "an adventure game whose name I don't remember who took some 30+ minutes to load from tape" ... I know it might have felt like it, but the data rate on the C64's built in tape routines is ~8KB/minute, so it really can't have been much over 8 minutes. :)

Comment: @Jules https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Datassette says ~4K/minute?

Comment: It could be that having to load the data twice to verify makes the difference?

Comment: @rwallace - suspect sh1 is correct: I calculated the figure from a description of the low level format, but didn't account for error correction overhead, which wasn't described on the page I was looking at.

Comment: I waited 30 mins for Manic Miner to load from tape many times.

Answer (score 3):

I used multiple Commodore 64s in the past, and I do not remember any of them ever having a cartridge slot. If any of them did, I never noticed them nor used them, and nobody I knew ever even mentioned anything about cartridges on their C64s. Though it's possible I (and others) somehow completely overlooked a cartridge slot, I don't think we had them.

All of our gaming on the C64 was done on floppy disks. We had piles of them laying around, and we could even easily make our own. In fact, making my own games for the C64 was what got me into software engineering.

So...

1. Not everyone could use cartridge slots (even if only because they didn't *know* they had one). Even if they all did have the slot, the tech will die if people don't know they have it.
2. Indy game development (a.k.a: "backyard", "garage", or "home brew" game development) was a huge thing for the C64, so many game developers needed to be able to easily write to their medium and to have people copy it around, meaning floppies were used and not cartridges.
3. Also note that the trend seems to be the use of the cheapest media that is simple to mass produce. New releases these days are hopefully targeting millions of copies sold, so burning cheap optical discs for a penny or less each instead of paying a quarter or a dollar per cartridge (not sure how much it costs to mass produce them) can save a company millions of dollars. Though the dynamics were slightly different back then, the same principle likely applies.

I think my first point might be a lynch-pin though. If you ask people "Why aren't you using a sprocket?" and the response is "Sprocket? What sprocket?" then that does not bode well for you.

Comment: @Arron, you probably just didn't notice it. Every C64 I ever saw in the UK, Europe and US had them, as did the C128 that followed.

Comment: cartridge slot == [Expansion](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Expansion_Port) port, the one under the power LED

Comment: @DavidPartington I used the C128 too, but I also don't remember a cartridge slot on that one either. If I can dig out my old C64, I'll see if I can find this slot on it, though I don't remember where I left the thing. Still, OP's question left me with the feeling I described in my answer: "Cartridge slot? What cartridge slot? All those years playing games on my C64 and I never knew I could play cartridge based games on it?"

Comment: The cartridge slot is the one labeled "Expansion".  Cartridge games were really only a thing very early in the C64's lifetime though.  Later on the most common use was for a FastLoad cartridge to speed up disk access, or maybe an REU if you used GEOS.  And yes, the C128 maintains the same cartridge slot and C64 cartridge games will work in it.

http://markus.brenner.de/cartridge/dump1.jpg

Comment: `Not everyone could use cartridge slots (even if only because they didn't know they had one` Sorry but that's a pretty dumb satement. If everyone's favourite games were on cartridges, people would surely look for the slot and find it.

Comment: @Bregalad wrote "Sorry but that's a pretty dumb statement" Speak for yourself. That statement does not even make sense. Why would I look for a slot that I did not believe existed? And why would anyone buy their favorite games on a media they didn't think they could use? That would be like Nintendo 64 users buying a copy of Elder Scrolls then looking for a CD drive on their N64. Someone who does not believe their N64 has a CD drive is not going to buy the game. If you later show them it _does_ have a CD drive, great! But your logic is failing here.

Comment: @Aaron In an initial situation where you just bought your brand new C64 and are looking for games, if there was a significant portion of popular games on cartridge, there wouldn't be people ignoring the cartridge slot's existence. I hold by the claim the idea that people didn't make games on cartridge just because C64 owners ignored the cartridge slot's existance is ridiculous, and no I doubt my logic is failing.

Comment: @Bregalad wrote "if there was a significant portion of popular games on cartridge..." And there was! I saw the cartridge games in the PC shop, but I assumed they were for some other system, or that you needed some special peripheral cartridge reader. The cartridges themselves were there, yet nobody I know ever had any cartridges that I know of, and I would be willing to bet multiple people I'm thinking of did not realize they could use the cartridges. In fact, I'll even ask them later. As for logic: your last comment was fine, but "If A exists, surely everyone will find it" was bad logic.

Comment: @Aaron Ok, you answer didn't mention that part (that there was cartridge games nobody tought were compatible with their C64s). The marketing/packaging should have been really horrible if people thought they were for some other system.